# How to get out of root mode in Windows bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm playing around with the bash shell for Windows 10 and I noticed that I was in the root mode (`whoami` returns `root`). I'm still fairly fresh at bash but I know enough to know that using root mode is dangerous if you don't absolutely know what you're doing (like me).

`exit` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> don't work.

Any tips to log out of `sudo`?

EDIT: I created a new user account with `adduser` and it took me out of root mode.

Comment: What happens with Ctrl-D and `exit`? Also, add the output of `env`, please.

Comment: There was no output. The window would just close. I think what was happening was that there was no user in the system so it defaulted to the root. I added a new user and it took me out of root and into that user mode so I think I'm all good now

Comment: You should use "@" followed by username to reply to someone, for example @muru

Comment: @HughO'Brien oh. The default user of WSL unless you created one is indeed root. Root on WSL != Administrator on Windows, so you can't do any real damage using it.

Comment: You must [change the default user for the WSL bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816732/how-to-change-default-user-in-wsl-ubuntu-bash-on-windows-10). In a Windows command line, `LxRun.exe /setdefaultuser <new_name>`

Comment: @Jaime - and mark this as a duplicate so that quality answers to common questions can be maintained.