# In WSL, how do I change from root to my user_account?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

So recently I had to change my WSL ubuntu terminal password. I changed the password via root access. But now I cannot seem to revert back to my user-account. This is because I have forgotten the user_account name.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the root account, you can check the password database. Your non-system users will normally have UIDs in the range 1000 - 65533. So for example:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$3>999 && $3<65534'
```

Alternatively just look at the contents of the `/home` directory, since by default users' home directories are created with the same name as the username:

```
ls /home
```

Using this information, you should then be able to set the default user using the method described here:

- [How to change default user in WSL Ubuntu bash on Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816732/how-to-change-default-user-in-wsl-ubuntu-bash-on-windows-10)