# How can I go away from root user in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to type in 'exit' and tried cntrl+d too but they both just close the terminal.
Why is this? Is there another way to move away from root user?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking [How to change default user in WSL Ubuntu bash on Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816732/how-to-change-default-user-in-wsl-ubuntu-bash-on-windows-10)

Comment: That is indeed the same question, But if I type in this:  'ubuntu2004 config --default-user <username>'  I get this returned:  'ubuntu2004: command not found'

Comment: Are you typing it in the Ubuntu terminal? You need to type it in a Windows `cmd.exe` or PowerShell window

Comment: Yes I was typing it in the ubuntu terminal. Now I typed it in cmd.exe and PowerShell window where I receive in both cases:      /usr/bin/id: ‘younes’: no such user

Comment: You will need to figure out your non-root username from inside Ubuntu ex. `awk -F: '$3>999 && $3<65534' /etc/passwd` (I don't think there's a way to list WSL usernames from the Windows side)

Comment: Hi, I think I solved the problem by using useradd. After that I changed from root user to the other non root user by the following command: su - <username>. Feel free to share your thoughts about this approach. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can alway switch users with `su`. simply use

```
su <username>
```

Comment: I see why it wasn't possible. I only have one account, which is the administrator account. Is this harmful/risky?

Comment: root and admin are NOT the same. always using root is however indeed not recommended since you might accidentialy break or change something, that you are not supposed to. if you need root privileges temporarily you should use `sudo`

Comment: if your username is something other than root, then it is not root but propably admin (capable of `sudo` and such but not everything)