# How do I change my default root-user to non-root user?

Tags: command-line, login, root, users

When opening my terminal (Ubuntu16.04) I am logged in as root. Everytime I have to type this command 'su - ' to log in as non-root user. So I already made a non-root user but how do I set this non-root user as default?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you set up your system to act this way in the first place? Reverse that. What you describe is not a default behaviour of an Ubuntu system. What is more: the root account is disabled by default. Check your `.bashrc` file to see what is happening when a terminal is opened.

Comment: I made my non-root user using the command "adduser". If I change from root to non-root I don't have to type in a password. I do have to type in a password when going to root from non-root user. I can't find anything particular in the .bashrc file. Where do I have to look specifically within the .bashrc file?

Comment: How did you manage to have the root account in the first place? This is not how Ubuntu works by default. `su - ` does not proceed on a standard Ubuntu install. Are you graphically also logging in the root account?

Comment: I don't know how I managed to have the root user, but it was there from the beginning I think. It's quite some time ago that I installed Ubuntu. I only use the GUI for text editors, plotting and CFD simulations.

Comment: You tell that `su -` logs you in as a non-root user? `su -`, on systems that enable the root account, switches one to root, so please also check that statement in your question and eventually correct it. How do you know/recognize you are suddenly in a root account when you merely open the terminal?

Comment: Actually, that's exaclty what I meant. When opening the terminal I recognize I'm in the root account because it shows the following before typing in any command: root@DESKTOP-68URG92: <Command>

Comment: That could only happen if you are logged in in the graphical environment as user "root". That a colon is displayed after the command suggests indeed that you may be logging in as a user with login name "root". A prompt with elevated privileges ends with "#" in Ubuntu (and Debian, I suspect). You probably should just create a fresh account with toot privileges for yourself to solve the issue.

Comment: I think you will find this interesting. https://askubuntu.com/questions/816732/how-to-change-default-user-in-wsl-ubuntu-bash-on-windows-10