# How to change default user in WSL Ubuntu when distro not installed from Microsoft Store

Tags: command-line, windows-10, users, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've imported a WSL image I had exported from WSL previously (`wsl --import UbuntuTest ./UbuntuImport .\UbuntuSnapshot201011`).

My distro has been correctly installed as `UbuntuTest`. However, when I log into it with `wsl -d UbuntuTest` the default user is root, and not `roemerco`. I would like to change it, so that I can login just with `wsl -d UbuntuTest` not needing the CLI option `-u roemerco` in addition.

Apparently, for many users, it's possible to change default users by running a command like `ubuntu config --default-user <username>` (see [How to change default user in WSL Ubuntu bash on Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/q/816732/686407)). However, this doesn't work in my case. Neither on CMD nor Powershell is `ubuntu` or `ubuntu2004` a recognised command. This may be, because I haven't installed the distro through the Microsoft Store.

Does anyone have any thoughts? I tried to find stuff in the WSL docu, but couldn't find anything about it. Is this a missing feature or bug?

Comment: Yes it does, the distro works properly. It's just that it uses root by default and I don't know how to change it. The `ubuntu2004` command doesn't exist.

Comment: @steeldriver I've tried that already both from `CMD` and `PS`, neither works: `'UbuntuTest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` and `UbuntuTest : The term 'UbuntuTest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, etc.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there's a much discussed [issue for exactly my problem on `WSL` Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3974). There are two methods to solve the problem: a) registry hack, b) editing a config file. The powershell registry hack worked for me:

```
Get-ItemProperty Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\*\ DistributionName `
| Where-Object -Property DistributionName -eq UbuntuTest `
| Set-ItemProperty -Name DefaultUid -Value 1000
```

Replace `UbuntuTest` with your respective distro name.